# Reactjs and inertia js filter problom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel, inertiajs

I am having a problem for a couple of weeks now trying to solve it

I am using Laravel and React js along with Inertia js. I have a react component that searches for users it has a couple of filters like skills, name, city, etc ..

But skills are multiple choices as you would see in the code below.

the problem is when I visit the page it makes a get request twice I do not know why?
is it because the useEffect! or some state has changed,

```
import TextInput from "@/Components/TextInput";
import DefaultLayout from "@/Layouts/DefaultLayout"
import { Inertia } from "@inertiajs/inertia";
import { Head, usePage } from "@inertiajs/inertia-react"
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import debounce from "lodash/debounce";
import CreatrosCard from './Components/CreatorsCard'
import Select from 'react-select'
import { useLaravelReactI18n } from "laravel-react-i18n";
import CountriesSelect from "@/Components/Shared/CountriesSelect";
import CitiesSelect from "@/Components/Shared/CitiesSelect";
import InputLabel from "@/Components/InputLabel";

export default function SearchCreators() {
    // const countries = usePage().props.countries;
    const cities = usePage().props.cities;
    const creators = usePage().props.creators;
    const filters = usePage().props.filters;
    const skills = usePage().props.skills;
    const specializations = usePage().props.specializations;
    const [searchKeyword, setSearchKeyword] = useState(filters.search);
    const [selectedSpecializationIds, setSelectSpecializationIds] = useState([]);
    const [selectedSkillsIds, setSelectedSkillsId] = useState([]);
    const [gender, setGender] = useState(filters.gender);
    // const [country, setCountry] = useState(filters.country);
    const [city, setCity] = useState(filters.city);

    const { t, getActiveLanguage } = useLaravelReactI18n();

    const genderOptions = [
        {
            id: 1,
            label: t('Male'),
            value: 'male'
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            label: t('Female'),
            value: 'female'
        }
    ]

    const handleSearch = (event) => {
        setSearchKeyword(event.target.value);
    }

    const handleSpecializationChange = (event) => {
        const previousIds = selectedSpecializationIds;
        const nextId = parseInt(event.target.value);
        const itemIndex = previousIds.indexOf(nextId);
        if (itemIndex !== -1) {
            previousIds.splice(itemIndex, 1);
        } else {
            previousIds.push(nextId);
        }
        setSelectSpecializationIds([...previousIds]);
    }

    const handleSkillsChange = (event) => {
        const getSkillsIds = event.map(skill => skill.id);
        setSelectedSkillsId(getSkillsIds)
    }

    const handleGenderChange = (event) => {
        setGender(event.value);
    }
    const debouncedSearch = debounce(() => {
        Inertia.get(route('creators.search'),
            { search: searchKeyword, specialization: selectedSpecializationIds, skills: selectedSkillsIds, gender: gender, city: city },
            {
                queryStringArrayFormat: "indices",
                preserveScroll: true,
                preserveState: true,
                replace: true
            });
    }, 500);

    useEffect(() => {
        debouncedSearch();
    }, [selectedSpecializationIds, selectedSkillsIds, searchKeyword, gender, city])

    // const handleContryChange = (e) => {
    //     setCountry(e.target.value)
    // }

    const handleCityChange = (e) => {
        setCity(e.target.value)
    }

    return (
        <DefaultLayout header={<h2 className="font-semibold text-xl text-gray-800 leading-tight">{t('Search for creators')}</h2>}>
            <Head title={t('Search for creators')} />

            <section className="py-8">
                <div className="max-w-7xl mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8 space-y-6">
                    <div className="grid grid-cols-4 gap-6">
                        <div className="col-span-1">
                            <div>
                                <TextInput
                                    id="search"
                                    type="text"
                                    value={searchKeyword ? searchKeyword : ''}
                                    className="mt-1 block w-full h-12 p-2"
                                    handleChange={handleSearch}
                                    placeholder={t('Search creator name')}
                                />
                            </div>


                            <div className="mt-4">
                                <h1 className="text-lg text-gray-800 mb-3">{t('Categories')}</h1>
                                <div>
                                    {specializations.map((specialization, index) => (
                                        <div key={specialization.id} className="flex items-center gap-3 mb-3">
                                            <input
                                                className="w-4 h-4 text-[#6F3F70] bg-gray-100 rounded border-gray-300 focus:ring-[#6F3F70]"
                                                onChange={event => handleSpecializationChange(event, index)}
                                                id={specialization.id}
                                                type="checkbox"
                                                value={specialization.id}
                                            />
                                            <label htmlFor={specialization.id} className="text-gray-800">{specialization.title[getActiveLanguage()]}</label>
                                        </div>
                                    ))}
                                </div>
                                <div className="mt-6">
                                    <h1 className="text-lg text-gray-800 mb-3">{t('Skills')}</h1>
                                    <Select
                                        id="skills"
                                        name="skills"
                                        isMulti
                                        onChange={event => handleSkillsChange(event)}
                                        options={skills?.filter(skill => selectedSpecializationIds.includes(skill.parent_id))}
                                        placeholder={t('Select Skills')}
                                        getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title[getActiveLanguage()]}
                                        getOptionValue={(option) => option.id}
                                    />
                                </div>
                                <div className="mt-6">
                                    <h1 className="text-lg text-gray-800 mb-3">{t('Gender')}</h1>
                                    <Select
                                        value={
                                            genderOptions.filter(option =>
                                                option.value === t(gender))
                                        }
                                        onChange={handleGenderChange}
                                        name="gender"
                                        options={genderOptions}
                                        classNamePrefix="select"
                                        placeholder={t('Gender')}
                                    />
                                </div>

                                {/* <div className="mt-6">
                                    <InputLabel className={'text-lg text-gray-800 mb-3'} for="country" value={t('Country')} />

                                    <CountriesSelect
                                        value={country ? country : ''}
                                        options={countries}
                                        handleChange={handleContryChange}
                                        className='border-gray-300 p-3 bg-white border focus:border-[#804b80] text-gray-500 focus:ring-indigo-500 rounded-md shadow-sm mt-1 block w-full'
                                    />

                                </div> */}

                                <div className="mt-6">
                                    <InputLabel className={'text-lg text-gray-800 mb-3'} for="country" value={t('City')} />

                                    <CitiesSelect
                                        value={city ? city : ''}
                                        options={cities}
                                        handleChange={handleCityChange}
                                        className='border-gray-300 p-3 bg-white border focus:border-[#804b80] text-gray-500 focus:ring-indigo-500 rounded-md shadow-sm mt-1 block w-full'
                                    />

                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <div className="col-span-3">
                            <div className='grid grid-cols-3 gap-6'>
                                {creators.data.map(creator => {
                                    return (
                                        <CreatrosCard key={creator.id} creator={creator} t={t} />
                                    )
                                })}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>

        </DefaultLayout>
    )
}
```

I know the code is too long, but any idea what's happening?

[image: The Requests after i visit the page.]